How to swap git history of 2 identical files
Imagine I have 2 identical files:

One is old with a long history.
One is brand new.

I want to swap the history of these 2 files, essentially renaming the old file with name of new. I am planning to delete the old file soon.
How can I achieve this?
git mv oldFile newFile
keeps both histories intact.
I also don't want to make a commit, since I am trying to do this programmatically.

You cannot create new history without making a commit.

You can create/make commits programmatically.

Do you already have a commit in your repository, where both oldfile and newfile live together ? if yes: you will have a hard time making git rename detection map newfile to oldfile. If no: run git mv then create a commit.

Your question also mentions "I am trying to do this programmatically": would you care to explain what part you intend to program ?

@LeGEC > Do you already have a commit in your repository, where both oldfile and newfile live together
Yes.

I need to programmatically only keep git history, but not commit anything. Since commit history for this step needs to contain 1 commit and it's contents need to be verified before pushing it to version control.

If this is a completely private repository that only you work towards, doing this could be okay. However, if this is a public repository and the commit history you are modifying is already publicly available in remote, you should not do this. Rewriting history of public branches is bad practice in git.
See this question and this question. (Neither answer your question, but both provide insights about rewriting public history)
